# Mongoose compare with a third level nested field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**I have the following collections:** [image]

and I would like to do a find from collection1 all the way to collection 3 and 4 to compare name in one query.

**example:**

```
collection1.find({
    collection2.collection3.name: req.body.name3,
    collection2.collection4.name: req.body.name4
}).exec()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **lookup**, **unwind** and **match**, here is untested solution of your problem

```
 Model.aggregate([
     {
         $match: {
             _id: req.params.id
             // for object id use
             // _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
         }
     },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "collection2",
            localField: "collection2",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Collection2"
          }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$ColelctionTwo"
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "collection3",
            localField: "CollectionTwo.collection3",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Collection3"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "collection4",
            localField: "CollectionTwo.collection4",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Collection4"
          }
        }
      ]).exec(function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
              // handle here
          }
          if(result) {
              // do something here...
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongodb aggregate framework's [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) or [$graphlookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) stages for multi collection queries. Mongoose docs for aggregation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Aggregate
You cannot do a simple find query for multi collection lookups.